# How to make a dictionary with the following list and add tuples to the value if the key is the same

Tags: python-3.x

`[['20MAY17', ('TOLL2', 9817.73)], ['23MAY17', ('TOLL2', 6497.36)], ['13MAY17', ('TOLL4', 9803.42)], ['5MAY17', ('TOLL3', 6677.66)], ['16MAY17', ('TOLL4', 1565.78)], ['12MAY17', ('TOLL2', 5680.84)], ['16MAY17', ('TOLL3', 7949.97)], ['6MAY17', ('TOLL2', 2420.46)], ['28MAY17', ('TOLL3', 6405.19)], ['22MAY17', ('TOLL4', 4022.52)], ['11MAY17', ('TOLL4', 4832.2699999999995)], ['27MAY17', ('TOLL3', 8878.97)], ['28MAY17', ('TOLL4', 1358.27)], ['17MAY17', ('TOLL4', 4150.74)], ['20MAY17', ('TOLL3', 8395.49)], ['3MAY17', ('TOLL3', 5729.33)], ['23MAY17', ('TOLL4', 6827.51)], ['24MAY17', ('TOLL4', 1452.02)], ['8MAY17', ('TOLL1', 9863.36)], ['22MAY17', ('TOLL3', 8823.13)], ['18MAY17', ('TOLL1', 4584.25)], ['16MAY17', ('TOLL2', 3739.91)], ['15MAY17', ('TOLL1', 8640.64)], ['24MAY17', ('TOLL1', 3860.73)]]`

This is the list I have gotten to, I want to create a dictionary with the dates as the key and the tuples as the values. But append the tuples for the same date, as a dictionary does not have duplicates. Basically have something like.

`{'01MAY17': [('TOLL4', 6209.24), ('TOLL3', 1701.37)],
'23MAY17': [('TOLL1', 5667.23)]}`

Comment: Post what you have tried, and someone will help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well simply you can just do it this way:

```
sample_dict ={}


for key,value in data:
    if key in sample_dict.keys():
        sample_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        sample_dict.update({key:[value]})

print(sample_dict)
```

Note:Assuming data variable is already declared.I've tried the code and it works

Comment: OMG thank you so much, that was the most crucial step for my code

Comment: you wellcome,I hope you finish your code nicely done